# Need help for accuracy for the MONEY datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types

I am working on building an application for a banking institution where the accuracy for monetary transaction is very much essential. I am thinking of using the datatype `Money` in SQL Server.

So I need suggestion whether the datatype I am using is enough to provide accuracy or not? I also wanted to know which one if better if i use the `numeric` datatype or `Money` datatype?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some arguments for/against money here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal.aspx and here: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/browse_thread/thread/e19bf068e208dd5b/f79e614829931537?hl=en&lnk=st&q=author:kass+money+accuracy&pli=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search in the [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) would have revealed....

```
money
     -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807     8 bytes

smallmoney
     - 214,748.3648 to 214,748.3647                            4 bytes
```

The money and smallmoney data types are accurate to **a ten-thousandth of the monetary units** that they represent. *(that's four digits after the decimal point)*

---

Numeric data types that have fixed precision and scale.

```
decimal[ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]
```

Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are **from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1**. The ISO synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.

*p (precision)*

The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

*s (scale)*

The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

---

`Numeric` (or `Decimal` which is the same) certainly has the larger range - and you can tweak how many digits you need before or after the decimal point.

On the other hand - even `Money` is accurate to **one tenth of a thousandth** of dollars or Euros or whatever currency you're interested in - that's typically enough even for a bank....

So basically:

- if you need **more than 4 significant digits** after the decimal point, or **more than 15 digits before the decimal point** - pick `NUMERIC` / `DECIMAL`
- otherwise, `MONEY` will be just fine